# Cache difficult view

Tags: android, caching, view

Can I cache a view that takes a while to load?

It is a subclass of a library that is used to create a map. This view takes quite a while to load, but I don't know where this performance issue is exactly.

I use this view in a fragment across multiple activities. I want to simplify my code by caching this view, right after it is inflated, in a sort of makeshift after-the-constructor singleton, which I can check for `null` each time I try to load this view.

Now I have the problem that this view is inflated each time, so now I have the problem that I can't really add this to the view hierarchy.

`View` doesn't seem to have an `addView(view)` method, which I can use.

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: "but I don't know where this performance issue is exactly" -- then find out, by using tools like Traceview. "I use this view in a fragment across multiple activities" -- not an individual instance, you don't, unless you like memory leaks.

Comment: @CommonsWare the performance issue might not even be an issue but just the limitations of the device. It is inside a library so I can't just go in and fix things.